# How to solve padding issue on mobile mode

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I use grid-template-columns with 4 columns, wish 1 columns on mobile.

Here is my css setting:

```
<div style={{ padding: 16 }}>
  <div className={styles.cardContainer}>
    {data.map((value, index) => <div key={index} className={styles.card} />)}
  </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.cardContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(364px, 1fr));
  gap: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}
.card {
  min-height: 522px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid $color-neutral-30;
  background-color: $color-neutral-10;
  border-radius: 24px;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

It's working on desktop, but have padding-right issue on some mobile

[image]

It should padding-right 16px, how to solve it ?

Comment: `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(364px, 1fr));` it's probably coming from the min value.

Comment: min value coming from where ?

Comment: You're using `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(364px, 1fr));` where the min-size of the column will be 364px. That's probably too big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.cardContainer {
  display: grid;
  gap: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.card {
  min-height: 522px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid $color-neutral-30;
  background-color: $color-neutral-10;
  border-radius: 24px;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  /* For devices with a width of 576px or more (e.g., small mobile landscape) */
  .cardContainer {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* For devices with a width of 768px or more (e.g., tablets) */
  .cardContainer {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  /* For devices with a width of 992px or more (e.g., larger tablets and desktops) */
  .cardContainer {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}

/* You can add more media queries for other breakpoints as needed */
```

**Note:**
With this CSS, the .cardContainer will have a single column layout on mobile devices, and the number of columns will increase as the device width increases. The media queries define different column layouts for different screen sizes.

Adjust the breakpoints (e.g., 576px, 768px, 992px) and the number of columns according to your design requirements. The key is to use media queries to adapt the grid layout to different screen sizes and prevent the padding issue on mobile devices.

#css #html